# showOpenDialog Debajo de todas las demás ventanas

Tags: java

Hola buenas tengo un problema, al hacer click en el botón que me abre el explorador se queda debajo de las demás ventanas y no se ve. Al principio creía que era mi problema, pero es que si pruebo ese jframe me aparece encima del jframe. Pero al llamarlo desde la aplicación, no sé porqué aparece debajo de todas las demás jframes, os enseñaría una captura, pero no tiene sentido ya que no se vé.

```
JFileChooser fcAbrir = new JFileChooser();
            fcAbrir.setLocation(700, 500);
            int valorDevuelto = fcAbrir.showOpenDialog(frame);
            if(valorDevuelto == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fcAbrir.getSelectedFile();
                imagen = new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath());
                
                
            }
```

He intentado poner un setLocation, pero eso no hace nada. ¿Sabríais como ponerlo para que aparezca siempre encima de las demás ventanas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira probe tu codigo y cuando lo ejecute puse la ventana completa y todo va bien y el jfilechooser aparece arriba de todo pon el code asi y intenta

```
    JFileChooser fcAbrir = new JFileChooser();
    fcAbrir.setLocation(700, 500);
    Component frame = null;
    int valorDevuelto = fcAbrir.showOpenDialog(frame);
    if (valorDevuelto == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = fcAbrir.getSelectedFile();
        ImageIcon imagen = new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath());

    }
```